# Why camera capture is crashing after sometime in opencv with python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x

## OpenCV with python(MAC OS X EL Capitan)

I'm trying to implement simple color detection code in python using openCV.

following is my code example for color detection.

**hsvTracker.py**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while (1):
    #take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    #Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #define range of blue color in hsv
    lower_blue = np.array([110,100,100])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    #Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    #Bitwise-AND mask to the original image will give us tracked object
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

    cv.imshow('Frame',frame)
    cv.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv.imshow('res',res)
    k=cv.waitKey(7) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

When i run this code it works properly and blue color object is detected. But after some time this suddenly crashes and gives following **exception stack**. Is it really related to camera capture issue or is it related to something else in code?

[image: first image of stack trace]

[image: second image of stack trace]

Ask me if you want more details.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?